# Display selected radio button and check box on a msgbox when button1 is clicked VB

Tags: vb.net, oracle, vba, visual-studio, vbscript

So what I'm trying to do is create a MessageBox when Button1 is clicked with the selected Radiobuttons and Checkboxes on it.

Here's the design:

[image: [Picture]]

And I want the output to be something like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: So you want to get the text of the checked boxes or the status of them?

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily Yes, something like that on the Picture2. Just text of the selected RadioButtons and CheckBoxes.

Comment: Yes this is can be done, i'm going to bost an answer for you.

Comment: Read out the selections, concat into a string, output string via messagebox. Update your question with your state of the project so we know where to start.

Comment: @Mousa Alfhaily: Please don't encourage the use of SO as a free code writing service.

Comment: @David How can i help him if i did't give some code examples!!!?? Some times the problem is very hard to explain it without some codes.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry for that, But i really need some samples so that I could learn it by myself. I'm really new to this language and I hope someone can guide me through this.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily Thank you, I appreciate that.

Comment: @Mousa Alfhaily: Don't get me wrong, the fact that you want to do his homework is great. But it is not what SO is intended to be. We don't want the "Here is some text for my assignment, give me code" kind of questions, and one should not encourage people to ask them. Simple as that.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `oracle`? If you are trying to query a database then please update your question with the DDL statements you have used to create the database tables and the DML statements for your sample data and what **you** have tried to query the database and where the issue is.

Comment: @DavidG : Thanks, i get that, but it's really back to the guy who is asking for the code, so if he took the code, copy and paste it, then HE doesn't want to learn, but if he took your code and studed it and knew how it's working, then  you helped him, i don't know, this is what i thing, i have to do what i intended to do and the rest is back to him.

Comment: @Mousa Alfhaily: You showed him (and everyone else who sees your answer) that such questions might be answered in the future. He might not have tried himself, he might not have done the proper research etc. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide exists for a very good reason. Posting your assignment text on SO to get out working code is NOT an efficient and effective way to get your coding done, and rarely teaches anything. Please stick to the guidelines of Stackoverflow, with your questions AND with your answers. You can trust me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Better way of doing this is to loop through the groupbox controls and check if the checkboxes are checked and if yes append that to some string.And after all your checks are complete display the string using messagebox.Simple as it is.To provide some more light to the solutions please go through the below code

Looping through controls

```
        Dim strfinal As String
        For Each gb As Control In Me.Controls
            If gb.GetType() Is GetType(GroupBox) Then
                Dim str As String
                str = gb.Text
                For Each c As CheckBox In gb.Controls
                    If c.Checked = True Then
                        str = str + vbNewLine + c.Text
                    End If
                Next
                If str <> "" Then
                    strfinal = strfinal + vbNewLine + str
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

and displaying in messagebox

```
If strfinal <> "" Then
            MessageBox.Show(strfinal, "somecaption", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End If
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code is going to give you the result exactly as in picture2 above :

```
Dim Toppings As String = "Toppings:" & VbCrlf
Dim TSize As String = "Size:"
Dim CrustType As String = "Crust Type:"
```

Here when you press on Button1, when the name of the groubBox that contains the toppings is ' ToppingsGroupBox' and the same for the other groupBoxes:

```
For Each CB As CheckBox In ToppingsGroupBox.Controls
    If CB.Checked Then
        Toppings &= "-" & CB.Text & VbCrlf
    End If
End Each

For Each RB As RadioButton In SizesGroupBox.Controls
    If RB.Checked Then
        TSize &= RB.Text
    End If
End Each

For Each RB As RadioButton In CurstTypeGroupBox.Controls
    If RB.Checked Then
        CurstType &= RB.Text
    End If
End Each

If DineInRadioBox.Checked Then
    MsgBox(TSize & VbCrlf & CurstType & Toppings & "*Dine In")
Else
    MsgBox(TSize & VbCrlf & CurstType & Toppings & "*Take Out")
End If
```

**Hope that will help you :)**